# Can't run app via android studio on real android device

Tags: android-studio, android-logcat, app-launcher

After adding splash and other screens my app is not launching in the device through the Android Studio, Logcat shows that the package has been successfully installed but it doesn't get launched. Even the dialog box to choose the running device comes up but still no resolution of the problem till now. 
When I run it from the device menu, the app runs and any changes made by me is visible but why can't I run directly at the time of installation via android studio.

Here's my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.radio.orion.radio" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="RADIOUZ"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
    <activity android:name=".Splash"
       >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecondScreen"></activity>
    <activity android:name="Sign"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Navdrawer" >
    </activity>
 <activity android:name=".ArtistSong"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".DrawerExtrasNavigation"></activity>
<activity android:name=".DrawerStreamNavigation"></activity>
<activity android:name=".DrawerNavigation"></activity>
<activity android:name=".HomeDrawerNavigation"></activity>
<activity android:name=".Notes"></activity>
<activity android:name=".Wclock"></activity>
<activity android:name=".YourNews"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".WishSend"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />

</application>
</manifest>
```

Here is the run mesages after run:

> Installing com.radio.orion.radio
>       DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.radio.orion.radio"
>       pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.radio.orion.radio
>       Success
>       Launching application:     com.radio.orion.radio/com.radio.orion.radio.MainActivity.
>       DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start  -n  "com.radio.orion.radio/com.radio.orion.radio.MainActivity" -a 
>   android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>       Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat= [android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
>   cmp=com.radio.orion.radio/.MainActivity }
>       java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent {  act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] 
>   flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.radio.orion.radio/.MainActivity } from null
>   (pid=31967,  uid=2000) not exported from uid 10400
>       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1472)
>       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1426)
>       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerNative.java:
>   2720)
>       at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:680)
>       at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:270)
>       at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
>       at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:76)
>       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:243)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

And here is the logcat , when i run the app:

> 10-27 11:05:52.905  32138-32138/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ >>>>>>
>   AndroidRuntime    START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
>       10-27 11:05:52.905  32138-32138/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ CheckJNI is OFF
>       10-27 11:05:52.905  32138-32138/? I/AndroidRuntime﹕ Kernel Release Version:  3.10.20-262979-gaee3d1b
>       10-27 11:05:52.905  32138-32138/? I/dalvikvm﹕ No library specified. The standard exception handler will be used
>         10-27 11:05:52.925  32138-32138/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
>         10-27 11:05:52.925  32138-32138/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
>         10-27 11:05:52.925  32138-32138/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
>         10-27 11:05:52.925  32138-32138/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
>            10-27 11:05:52.925  32138-32138/? D/dalvikvm﹕ No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
>          10-27 11:05:52.935  32138-32138/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Extra Options: not specified
>          10-27 11:05:52.955  32138-32138/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 202 unimplemented (abstract)
>   methods
>          10-27 11:05:53.055  32138-32138/? E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 33
>          10-27 11:05:53.055  32138-32138/? E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 34
>          10-27 11:05:53.055  32138-32138/? E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 34
>          10-27 11:05:53.055  32138-32138/? E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 34
>          10-27 11:05:53.115  32138-32138/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am 10-27 11:05:53.125 
>   32138-32145/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 11 10-27
>   11:05:53.125  32138-32145/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 12
>   10-27 11:05:53.125  32138-32145/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for
>   JIT: 13 10-27 11:05:53.125  32138-32145/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena
>   pages for JIT: 14 10-27 11:05:53.125  32138-32145/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Total
>   arena pages for JIT: 15 10-27 11:05:53.125  32138-32145/? I/dalvikvm﹕
>   Total arena pages for JIT: 16 10-27 11:05:53.125  32138-32145/?
>   I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 17 10-27 11:05:53.135 
>   32138-32145/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 18 10-27
>   11:05:53.135  32138-32145/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 19
>   10-27 11:05:53.135  32138-32145/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for
>   JIT: 20
>       --------- beginning of /dev/log/system 10-27 11:05:53.155      535-864/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Force stopping com.radio.orion.radio
>   appid=10400 user=0: from pid 32138 10-27 11:05:53.165  32138-32138/?
>   D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM 10-27 11:05:53.165  32138-32143/?
>   D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 111K, 16% free 675K/804K, paused
>   0ms+1ms, total 3ms 10-27 11:05:53.165  32138-32145/? D/dalvikvm﹕
>   Compiler shutdown in progress - discarding request 10-27 11:05:53.165 
>   32138-32145/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Compiler shutdown in progress - discarding
>   request 10-27 11:05:53.165  32138-32145/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Compiler
>   shutdown in progress - discarding request 10-27 11:05:53.165 
>   32138-32145/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Compiler shutdown in progress - discarding
>   request 10-27 11:05:53.165  32138-32145/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Compiler
>   shutdown in progress - discarding request 10-27 11:05:53.165 
>   32138-32145/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Compiler shutdown in progress - discarding
>   request

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your splash and run splash

```
Thread timerThread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(3500);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };
    timerThread.start();
```

Comment: if you are getting any problem repost the issues again

Comment: i tried your answer. Splash screen is still not showing up!! :(

Comment: Now the app icon is not showing up in the menu of device

Comment: first clean your project now by going BUILD menu. and then yurn off and on your usb debugging via developer options. if still didn't worked try reinstalling ADB interface. i think you are using windows pc isn't it?

Comment: yeah i am using windows 7

Comment: ok.then reinstall USB driver https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126818/discussion-between-ananya-srivastav-and-prashant-sawant).